# Paypal Chained Payments calcuation

Tags: paypal, transactions, paypal-adaptive-payments

Been searching for a while.  This info should not be so difficult to find....

I provide a software service and want to take a small fee per transaction.   I have determined that I likely want to use a chained (instead of parallel) payment so it will show up to the end user as one transaction coming from who they expect, my part being invisible to them.

I understand transaction fees can be distributed a number of ways, my question is - in this scenario, do the paypal fees work like stripe.com where it is treated as one transaction and the primary would pay a single transaction fee on the full amount & I receive my part without any fees, or is it going to be treated as two transactions, each with it's own 2.x% + $.30.

It's a big deal since my side may only be $1 per transaction.

If it's considered two transactions, would my portion then at least be treated as a "micro payment" and be subject to 5% + $.05 instead of the amount for a "normal" transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction fee will treated in a single transaction. If you required the primary receiver pay the full fees, then only the primary receiver will pay for it and you as a secondary receiver receive a full amount without any fees being applied even if you have micropayment rate in your account. The fee of the transaction will be taken from the transaction fee in the PayPal account individually. I've put a summary below from the PayPal [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/).

- SENDER – Sender pays all fees (for personal, implicit simple/parallel payments; do not use for chained or unilateral payments)
- PRIMARYRECEIVER – Primary receiver pays all fees (chained payments only)
- EACHRECEIVER – Each receiver pays their own fee (default, personal and unilateral payments)
- SECONDARYONLY – Secondary receivers pay all fees (use only for chained payments with one secondary receiver)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.   I've read the docs but unless I missed it, they did not specify how the transaction itself was handled - as one transaction or many.    Many Thanks!